# Back Navigation in Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation

I have done some research on this and came across several implementations that try to provide a solution to this problem. One among them was https://github.com/rathodchintan/Fragment-Back-Stack which seemed to work for most people.

I also tried methods such as:

```
        getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        getView().requestFocus();
        getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

on the onResume method but there are some problems that arise when i try use these.

In my case, i have on main fragment from which users can navigate to 8 other fragments from within it. There is also a navigation drawer with 4 items on it.

If a user navigates to any other fragments, and while using the `addToBackStack(null)` method during the transaction, some of the pages become slower. Also, when clicking the back button, the user has to navigate between all the other fragments added to the backstack even if they appear more than once.

What i am trying to achieve is a situation where changing fragments doesnt impact the performance of the fragment on the foreground and when navigating back, as long as the main fragment appears on the foreground, clicking back should close the application instead of having to go through every single fragment in the backstack.

Comment: `addToBackStack(null)` & `.executePendingTransactions()`

Comment: I still get the same result.